# Custom date format for Ubuntu

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, ubuntu, php-carbon

I am trying to run the following code on my new Ubuntu system:

```
$results = "FromMsSqlQuery";
$items = collect($results)->filter(function ($item) use ($now) {
    dd($item["StartDate"], $item["EndDate"]);
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('M j Y H:i:s:uA', $item["StartDate"]) <= $now
    && Carbon::createFromFormat('M j Y H:i:s:uA', $item["EndDate"]) >= $now;
});
```

My problem is that the current live server returns StartDate and EndDate in 'M j Y H:i:s:uA' format and my new server returns it in 'Y-m-d H:i:s' format. Therefore it throws an exception when trying a createFromFormat().

Is there a specific setting for SQL Server (remote [Azure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Azure) database) or Ubuntu that I could configure to return the date in 'M j Y H:i:s:uA' format?

Comment: You're running SQL Server on Ubuntu?

Comment: No. It's a remote azure database.

Comment: Did you try using  ```DATE_FORMAT``` mysql function

Comment: can you specify what OS your live server is and have you tried Carbon Parse https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-carbonparse-in-ddmmyyyy-format

Comment: Not used DATE_FORMAT as code is working on an old server. I am trying to configure a new Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS server

Comment: I assume you are using the same version of PHP on both LIVE and TEST?

Comment: Live is PHP 5.6.21-1+donate.sury.org~precise+2 (cli)

Comment: Test is PHP 5.6.21-5+donate.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli)

Comment: Ok, its just that I found [this](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/issues/282) but that was PHP7 related so never mind.

Comment: Live returns dates from query in 'M j Y H:i:s:uA' format and Test returns in  'Y-m-d H:i:s'

Comment: **Look its the return statement that is doing the conversion** of a standard MYSQL datetime to your `'M j Y H:i:s:uA'` date format. You need to work out why the 2 conversions in the return statement are failing. **Did you install Carbon** although I have never used it so I am not sure if it is even something that you need to install seperately

Comment: Actually a better question would be _Is this vanilla code from the live system_ or is this _code you have added_??????

Comment: Actually I just realised you are using SQLServer. What datatypes are the `StartDate` and `EndDate` defined as on your database

Answer (score 1):

MySQL DateTime data types are always stored as `Y-m-d H:i:s`

**Your problem is you have addded the line `dd()` which stands for `Dump and Die`**

So the script will never get to the following `return` statement which is what is doing the date conversion for you.

Remove the `dd($item["StartDate"], $item["EndDate"]);` line and the lines that follow it will run, which is what is doing the date conversion for you!

Comment: If I remove the dd(). I get the following Carbon exception. Carbon.php:Carbon\Carbon in createFromFormat: A textual month could not be found. Its only there for debug purposes :-)

Comment: Then that is another question completely

Comment: Try a simple `print_r($items);` instead. That will not kill your script. Also what does the `dd()` or `print_r()` show you